# Can we set a fixed height for div with display: table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, display, tablelayout

Here is my code:

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.column {
  display: table-cell;
  border: thin solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="column">
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  one one one one one one one one one one one
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  two two two two two two two
  </div>
  <div class="column">
  two two two two two two two
  </div>
</div>
```

The total height of `.wrapper` is much larger than `48px` (the height set in `.wrapper`). Is it possible to make `.wrapper` honor the height set via CSS?

Comment: Why do you want to use `display: table`? Why not Flexbox or Grid?

Comment: @m4n0 There is no specific reason to use `display: table`. I could use Flexbox too. I was learning different ways of creating layouts when I came across this problem and it made me wonder if a table layout will always expand its height based on its content or if there is a way to set it to a fixed max height.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an element with `display: table;` can have a defined height like that. You will need to wrap the element with another block element, then define the height on the parent:

```
<div style="height: 48px; overflow: auto;">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    one one one one one one one one one one one
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    two two two two two two two
    </div>
    <div class="column">
    two two two two two two two
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```